# Permutation of a vector and its sub elements using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, permutation

I have the vector below:

```
v={'T','AT','AS','C'};
```

I would like to see all the possible permutations for this vector. To do so I can use the  command below:

```
p=perms(v)
```

But I want to go one step further as each of the elements has sub index of 1 to 4, for example, T1,T2,T3,T4 .....C1,C2,C3,C4. I would like to have all the possible permutations with its sub index as see such results

```
T1,AT1,AS1,C1
C3,AT3,AS3,t3
AS2,AT2,C2,T2
     .
     .
     .
```

Could you please help me how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: v={'T','AT','AS','C'} when each of elements has index of 1:4

Comment: I assume subindices can't be repeated, like `T1` and `T2` can't appear together?

Comment: I don't know how to do it exactly :(

Comment: @gnovice Yes, it cant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first using [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate a set of indices for all your possible combinations:

```
v = {'T1', 'AT1', 'AS1', 'C1'; ...
     'T2', 'AT2', 'AS2', 'C2'; ...
     'T3', 'AT3', 'AS3', 'C3'; ...
     'T4', 'AT4', 'AS4', 'C4'};
[ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4] = ndgrid(1:4);
c = [v(ind1(:), 1) v(ind2(:), 2) v(ind3(:), 3) v(ind4(:), 4)];
```

And `c` will be a 256-by-4 cell array, as expected (4<sup>4</sup> combinations). Now you can expand each row by it's total number of permutations using [`perms`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) like so:

```
p = perms(1:4);
p = reshape(c(:, p.').', 4, []).';
```

And `p` will be a 6144-by-4 cell array, also as expected (24 permutations times 256 combinations).

Comment: Thanks, alot..you helped :) but the thing is, I want a permutation between T,AT,AS and C as well as their indexes. The one that you gave me only works on indexes but now on order of sub elements.

Comment: @Juliette: Sorry. My first version only gave the number of *combinations*. My new answer shows how to get the total *permutations* of those combinations.

Comment: Thanks..you helped a lot!